# DAO .Execute method fails in Access mde

Tags: ms-access, dao

First off, I'm using Access 2000 and DAO.  I have code that executes a simple INSERT INTO query that I call using db.Execute.  This code works fine inside an mdb.  However, if I compile into an mde then I get

> error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument

on this line and the record does not get inserted.  However, if I change from db.Execute to DoCmd.RunSQL using the exact same SQL statement the record is inserted with no problems.  Does anyone know why the DAO Execute method of the DAO database object would suddenly stop working once I compile into an MDE?

*Note*:  I only get the error if I specify the dbFailOnError option of the .Execute method.  If I leave that option off, I get no error but the record is still not inserted.

EDIT:
This line fails in the MDE (*but works fine in the MDB*):

```
App.db.Execute InsertSQL, dbFailOnError
```

From the immediate window with a breakpoint on the above line of code:

```
?InsertSQL
INSERT INTO Changes
(PropertyID, FieldID, [Which], [When], [Before], Reason, ReportChange)
VALUES (1, 2, "M", #2/19/2010 4:51:44 PM#, "Suite 2; 430 W KING ST; ABBOTTSTOWN, PA 17301-9771", "Per Owner", True)
```

(I have an entire class module dedicated to building and executing SQL statements, so it's not really practical to show exactly how I built the InsertSQL string variable.  However, I really don't think that is relevant.)

This line works everywhere:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL InsertSQL
```

EDIT: App.db definition (note that there is no reference in my project to ADO, only DAO):

```
Public App As New clsApp
```

clsApp class module (relevant lines only):

```
Private m_objDB As Database

Public Property Get db() As Database
    Set db = m_objDB
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_objDB = CurrentDb
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_objDB = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you are curious, I use App.db rather than CurrentDB for two main reasons: 1) slight performance gain by not having to call the CurrentDB function repeatedly (call it once then just refer to the object it returns) and 2) properties of the database object like .RecordsAffected always return relevant information.  Plus, it's faster to type.  And I'm a programmer, so I'm inherently lazy.

EDIT: Let me first apologize to those who have been following this thread and trying to help me.  It seems I may have left out the critical details of my problem.  The App.db.Execute call takes place inside a class module (clsSQL) and it references a global variable named App which is itself an instance of a different class module (clsApp).  I'm guessing the problem is that I am referring to an instance of a class module from within another class module.  Can anyone confirm if calling one class module from within another is something that is supported by MDBs and not MDEs? [*It is not an issue.  I was way over-thinking this.  See my answer for the full story.*]

Comment: Post your line of code.  If you are creating the Insert string in other lines of code include those lines too.

Comment: That helps.  Now how is app.db defined and set?   That's unusual syntax.  I've always used currentdb.execute strSQL, Dbfailonerror.

Comment: I don't understand this line of code: App.db.Execute . Where is the App object initialized and what kind of object is it? And what is the child object db?

Comment: DoCmd.RunSQL famously eats errors, so the fact that it appears to work doesn't tell you anything at all.

Comment: Have you decompiled the MDB? The reason I ask is that perhaps the MDB is not compiling correctly, and converting to MDE gets rid of whatever problem is causing the MDB to compile wrong.

Comment: I just did a decompile (great idea, don't know why I hadn't tried that already) but no luck.  As for DoCmd.RunSQL, while it may be hiding some error, it is successfully inserting the record.  That seems to tell me there is not a problem with the SQL statement itself.

Comment: The fact that it's inserting the record doesn't mean it's not producing an error. All it means is that it's possibly producing an error that does not prevent insertion of the record (e.g., one field's data is not inserted, but the record as a whole is).

Comment: I assume your class module does more than function as a wrapper around CurrentDB. You might have a look at my dbLocal function as an alternative way of doing the same thing (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833746/ms-access-is-there-a-significant-overhead-when-using-currentdb-as-opposed-to-dbe).

Comment: As to your most recent question about class modules referencing class modules, that shouldn't be an issue either in an MDB or an MDE. If it compiles in a freshly decompiled MDB, it will compile in an MDE, and if it compiles it's supposed to work unless there's some runtime or data-related difference in the two contexts. Just to clarify: you *are* running the MDB and MDE versions on the same computer in the same version of Access, right?

Comment: Yes, I am running the MDB and MDE versions on the same computer and in the same version of Access.  As for the class module, it's original purpose was to wrap Application.Echo so that it is a property rather than a method, which allows me to check the status of the Application.Echo so that if I turn it off in a function but it's already off I don't turn it back on prematurely by blindly calling Application.Echo True at the end of the function.  The class module just became a convenient place to throw the db object.  But I digress...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, my sincere apologies to those who tried to help me with this.  As I find so frustrating when others ask questions, I left out the key piece of information because I did not think it was relevant.  Here was the *full* initialize procedure for my clsApp class module:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Application.Echo True
    m_bEcho = True

    Set m_objDB = CurrentDb
    m_sUser = GetUserName
    Set m_objStatus = New clsStatus
    m_sPgmName = Application.CurrentProject.Name
    m_sPgmName = Left(m_sPgmName, InStr(m_sPgmName, ".mdb") - 1)
End Sub
```

The key line is that last one.  When I compiled into an ".mde", the string ".mdb" was no longer present in the `CurrentProject.Name`.  As a result, the call to `InStr()` returned 0.  And `0 - 1 = -1`.  So I was passing a negative number as the Length parameter for the `Left()` function.  However, the length parameter cannot be negative.  It is most definitely an "Invalid <strike>procedure call or</strike> argument."

My simple fix was to remove the "mdb" from ".mdb" and just check for the location of the "."  This also works correctly with the ".accdb" and ".accde" 2007 extensions.

Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are using a forms control reference inside the string you are passing to the Execute statement.  That is me!ControlName is inside the quotes.  Change it so it's outside the quotes.  That is change ".... SELECT me!ControlName As Field1, Field2, Field3 ..." to ".... SELECT " & me!ControlName & " As Field1, Field2, Field3 ..."

Thus VBA can convert the value of the control name properly.  Docmd.RunSQL does this for you.  Execute does not.

Comment: Doesn't apply to this situation.  See my edit above.  Thanks for taking the time to help, though.

Answer (score -1):

What version of DAO do you have in your references? It might be that the older version is working fine on the mdb but fails on the mde. Try setting this to the latest version and compile it again

Comment: I would not blindly suggest using the latest version whatever it might be.   DAO 3.6 should be the version in the references and is the latest version.  It comeas as part of Windows 2000, XP, Vista and 7 so it would be rather unlikely to have a different version.   There is no newer version unless you want to use the ACE DAO which is part of A2007 and newer.  Which I wouldn't recommend for a variety of reasons although it might very well work.

Comment: You should use the version of DAO that goes with the version of Access you're using. If A2000, A2002, A2003, ADO 3.6, and if A2007, the ACE DAO version. No exceptions.

Comment: Prehaps I should have said use the correct version for the mde and not the "latest" version. I think the advice is still sound

Comment: DAO and MDE version are not really the relevant issues. It's MDE and VBA version, and each version of Access has its own version of VBA. That said, a 2000-produced MDE will run in 2002 and 2003 (and, I assume, 2007), and so forth (i.e., forward compatibility), but an A2002 MDE won't work in A2000 (not backward-compatible).

Comment: DAO 3.6 is indeed the version in the references.