# Why is my access database so slow when loading?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Firstly, I have read this article; [What is causing my access database to be so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716639/what-is-causing-my-access-database-to-be-so-slow)

But as it was 8 years ago I felt I could ask the question again.

I have an access 2016 database that has a backend sql server, that I use for all calculations on the database. The database is used to have multiple job data, and each user can switch between jobs to view the data.

It is fairly complex in terms of calculations, however the database itself is only 15mb in size. It almost takes 10 seconds to load each form all the time, which is almost unusable from the user point of view.

Is there any suggestions on the best ways to speed up the database? It is on a remote server and each user logs in to the remote server to use it. So there is no database splitting or anything. Again I am reading these articles online like http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm and http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performanceldblocking.htm.

But again, as it was discussed years ago I was just wondering was there a more up to date way of enabling the database to run quicker.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: _What_ takes 10 seconds to happen?  Are you running a query during this time, doing DML stuff, something else?

Comment: Hi Tim, it takes 10 seconds to load each form. So for example, when you click a job name it brings you to the financial report for that job, but this process is taking 10 seconds or longer. It says 'calculating..' on the bottom left corner during this time. But I moved all calculations to the backend sql server?

Comment: You should try to find out how much of those 10 seconds are being spent in latency (the time it takes for data to go to and from the database), and how much is actually spent by the database to do work.  You are in the best position to answer these questions.

Comment: Are you running a single query for all the calculations or thousands of different ones? It might help if you add snippets of the problem code to your question.

Comment: Start by profiling: [Profiling ODBC Driver Performance (ODBC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-how-to/profiling-odbc-driver-performance-odbc?view=sql-server-2017). Then come back when you've tracked down performance bottlenecks, and ask a specific question with a [mcve]. We can't track down what's hindering performance for your database without any info.

Comment: What happens if you directly open a linked table in Access that contains just a few records? If that is slow too, you have a configuration issue. If that is fast, your forms are pulling way too much data, or forcing a local processing of data that should run on the server.

Comment: Hi all, Erik - I will do that now. Andre - I don't think this is an issue. My biggest linked table opens almost instantaneously in access. Tim - Yes I will check the latency now in an attempt to improve it. I will get back with a perhaps more concrete question later today.

Comment: If you are using a remote desktop instance that is on the same server / backbone network as the SQL backend sever this should be very fast, as effectively they are running on the same network. I think you should check the SQL profiler as others have suggested, and see what is bogging things down.

Comment: *It says 'calculating..' on the bottom left corner during this time*. When I have had this problem, it was because my queries were really complex and based on previous queries based on previos queries based on previous queries and so on. The solution that worked for me was using all the SQL code of those queries and do an INSERT INTO temp table in my database, and then calling the data from that temp table. Problem solved. Did it with VBA to clean and insert the records every time. Until now, that database works good, (thanks god). Maybe that could help you out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**re: You *"moved the calculations to the back-end SQL Server"***

I assume you mean that you ***moved the data*** to the back-end server.  This doesn't mean the calculations happen there, or are any faster.

In fact, it's more likely to **increase** calculation time, because calculations are still done by whatever machine is running the query (your front end I assume, unless you did some fancy coding to execute SQL Stored Procedures, etc, on the back-end, and are retrieving your data from there).

...So now it's still the *same machine* performing the calculations as before -- but now the data *has to be pulled from the server* to the local machine each time you run a query, as opposed to before, when the data was already local.

---

### Common Culprits

Without seeing your database nobody can do much more than guess, and my guess would be that you have multiple poorly-designed queries populating each of these forms that are being opened.

...possibly various incarnations of the *same query* running over and over again?  For example, a common issue in my experience: Is there a combobox that lists employee names or other data, limited based on various criteria?  Perhaps similar queries have to be run for each form?  Possibly several queries for each of the several forms?

Duplicated workload like that needs to be streamlined, and how to do that depends on your situation. With the above example, a static table could be generated each time the employee list changes, which includes only the names that should be included in the combo boxes.  This table could be stored locally, and thereby could replace several repetitive queries that are being calculated several times each of the database is opened.

Another common mistake is using time-consuming custom functions within a query that has to run the function against thousands of records.  A function that takes a quarter second to run can become a real problem when it's called 10,000 times by a single query.

---

### Timing Each Step

A somewhat messy but effective way to determine which process(es) are contributing most of the delay is to go in and "heavily pepper" your code with calls to a procedure that will record how long each process takes to run.  (I just went through this which resulted in a drastic reduction in time required to process 'huge' files.)

Below is a procedure I slapped together as an example.  How much or how little you want to log depends on your situation (and how quickly you diagnose the problem).

Keep in mind that **this is intended for temporary use**, as it's going to add *additional processing time* (although not as much as your existing processes already do, by the sounds of it!)

---

### Example Implementation

When you open your database several things are probably happening. Perhaps you have an `AutoExec` macro that runs a procedure, which opens forms and run queries which call functions, etc.

The goal here is to figure out how long every one of those steps take.  Kind of a poor example but hopefully it makes sense:

```
Sub YourOnOpenProcedure()
                                '<-- add our logging sub here
    SomeProcessYouCall_1
                                '<-- add our logging sub here
    SomeProcessYouCall_1
                                '<-- add our logging sub here
    SomeFormYouOpen
                                '<-- add our logging sub here
    SomethingElseYouDo
                                '<-- add our logging sub here (no 'EventName')
End Sub

Function SomeFunctionCalledByYourQuery() As Integer
                                '<-- add our logging sub here
    SomeFunctionCalledByYourQuery = 1 + 2

End Function
```

---

### Procedure-Timing Procedure

Add this procedure and variables or something similar to a public module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit   ' <-- Always, especially when troubleshooting!

Public startTime As Single, prevEventName As String

Sub timeIt(eventName As String)
'call this sub with the name of an event/process/sub/form/etc you're about to run
'prints time of previous event, and prepare for the next one if specified
'specify an empty string ("") after the end of the last event to return the last runtime.
    If startTime <> 0 Then   'log the duration of the last event
        'log the previous event
        Debug.Print "-> " & prevEventName & ":",  Round(Timer - startTime, 1) & " seconds"

        'optional: log "event' in a local table  (needs table, see notes)
        'DoCmd.SetWarnings False 'supress record-append confirmation
        'DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into tblLog select '" & prevEventName & "' as eName, " & Timer - startTime & " as eRunTime"
        'DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        startTime = 0
        prevEventName = ""
    End If
    If eventName <> "" Then
        startTime = Timer 'prepare for the next event
        prevEventName = eventName
    End If
End Sub
```

Logging the data in a table is optional (see below for table setup) and depends on your situation, like the scope of this issue.  As is, it will report in the Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> from VBA to open).

personally I always opt on the side of "more data" and a few minutes of extra work can make it much easier to see which processes are consistently troublesome.

---

### Example Usage:

If we pretend the processes you're running are `MsgBox`'s:

```
Sub DemoProcedure()

    timeIt "msgbox1:Hi"
    MsgBox "hi"

    timeIt "msgbox2:Hello"
    MsgBox "hello"

    timeIt "msg3:Heya"
    MsgBox "heya"

    timeIt "msg4:Hola"
    MsgBox "hola"
    timeIt ""         '<-- call with empty string to get the last time

End Sub
```

---

### Example Output:

This produces output in the Immediate Window something like:

```
-> msgbox1:Hi:       1.2 seconds
-> msgbox2:Hello:    1.1 seconds
-> msg3:Heya:      222.7 seconds
-> msg4:Hola:        0.4 seconds
```

It's clear that my *msg "heya"* procedure is the problem here.  :)

---

### Logging to a table

To log the timing data to a local table (as well as to the Immediate Window), un-comment the three relevant lines in the code and add a table something like this:

[image: img]

It will log data, something like:

[image: img]

---

## Tips to improve Access database performance

1. Use **Compact and Repair**
2. Load ***only*** what you need
3. Make sure all of your tables have **primary keys**
4. Optimize by adding **secondary indexes**
5. **Split** the database

More information on these from the [source](https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/blog/2012/07/10/5-tips-to-make-your-access-database-super-fast/).

- FMS : [**Performance Tips to Speed up Your Access Databases**](http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/faster/)
- TechRepublic : [**10 easy ways to speed up an Access database**](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-easy-ways-to-speed-up-an-access-database/)
- Office Support : [**Help Access run faster**](https://support.office.com/article/help-access-run-faster-f6827763-bb5c-4f48-8457-7a14addab6be)
- KeyCdn : [**The Path to Improving Database Performance**](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/database-performance/)

...there are numerous other articles online with advice on improving Access performance.

The bottom line is it's not likely to be a single issue.  "Whole Database Health" including ultra-organization from the bottom-up is vital.  In same cases the cost:benefit ratio may even justify starting over and redesigning a "perfect" database , starting on the drawing board (literally!)...

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will get looking at each immediately.

Comment: Tell me you typed this answer in just 5 minutes and you are my new superhero. Great epic answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would first build a test form.

Bind the form to a “large” sql table.

Then try this code:

Docmd.OpenForm "frmTest",,,"id = 10"

In above, replace “10” with a known PK id of the table.

Does this form load slow, or fast?

If the form loads slow, then we can much determine that the “slow” loading of the form is NOT due to excessive data or too much data being pulled from the table. Keep in mind that the above command will ONLY pull the ONE record from the table.

So is this test form slow, or fast?

If the form is fast then we can eliminate issues of data connection, or access just taking its sweet time.

If the form loads slow, then data optimizing is NOT your issue.

The above test takes what, 30 seconds to cook up and test. Just create the bound form, save it, and then whack ctrl-g, and enter the above docmd.OpenForm in the debug window.

If above is fast, then obviosity forms are causing pulls of data that is excessive.

And even better would be to create a stand-alone test accDB with just the one linked table, and the one test form. Again, test – is it fast or slow?

If the form loads fast, then we back to the actual application having something wrong. For example, non-existing printers, or linked to OTHER mdb/accdb files is the next issue I would look at (if the test form runs fast).

The other issue is you don’t mention where the location of the SQL server is, and is some type of “wan” involved in this connection (say sql running on a web site, or in some other building/location in which you using WAN as opposed to a LAN to connect to that database.

I regular hit sql server tables with 3+ million rows, and the form despite being bound DIRECTLY to that large table, we see and find loads are less than 1 second.