# How to get count of db recordsets/references (to debug err #3048 - can't open more databases)?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I started getting error 3048 - Can't open more databases.
I seem to have tamed it by implementing a single, static database variable
in a function "dbLocal()" after [David Fenton's example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833746/ms-access-is-there-a-significant-overhead-when-using-currentdb-as-opposed-to-db).

I would still like to monitor the number of database references to see how close I am getting to the 2048 limit in Access. I have tried to use .Recordsets.Count but it always returns zero. How can I determine the reference/recordset count being used internally by Access?

One place I've tried to look at it is in the "dbLocal()" function. Stripped down to less-than-bare-minimum here (in my code I use Fenton's full example), I'm trying this:

```
Public Function dbLocal() As DAO.Database

    Static dbCurrent As DAO.Database

    If dbCurrent Is Nothing Then
        Set dbCurrent = CurrentDb()
    End If
    Set CurDb = dbCurrent
    Debug.Print dbCurrent.Recordsets.Count

End Function
```

but it always prints zero. Even if it worked, it's not what I really want, because (if I am understanding correctly) Access is maintaining its own accounting that includes references due to queries, combo-boxes, etc., whereas my static variable would only "know about" references due to VBA statements explicitly using this dbLocal() function.

Is there a way to get a peek at Access' internal accounting to know how close I might be to exhausting the 2048 maximum?

In case it matters: Windows XP Pro SP3; Access 2010 32-bit version 14.0.6024.1000 SP1 MSO 14.0.6112.5000.

Comment: Sadly, you won't get an answer from David W. Fenton as he passed away last month :(

Comment: @onedaywhen That is sad. I wondered why he was not around. Do you know if there is a remembrance page?

Comment: @Remou: me too and I found [this](http://www.davis-andersonfuneralhome.com/obits/obituaries.php/obitID/435707/obit/David-W-Fenton) and [this](http://arnoldzwicky.wordpress.com/2011/11/03/david-fenton/). I will genuinely miss him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to just keep opening recordsets until you get an error:

```
Function TablesAvailable() As Integer
Dim i As Integer, rs As DAO.Recordset, rsColl As Collection

    On Error GoTo Err_TablesAvailable

    Set rsColl = New Collection
    Do While i < 4096
        i = i + 1
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT 1")
        rsColl.Add rs
    Loop

Exit_TablesAvailable:
    For Each rs In rsColl
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    Next rs
    Exit Function
Err_TablesAvailable:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 3048 'Cannot open any more databases.
        TablesAvailable = i
    Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End Select
    Resume Exit_TablesAvailable
End Function
```

Comment: I'll give this a try now. Needless to say, I'm curious as to whether/how .Recordsets.Count (or some direct equivalent) can be made to work (because there ought to be a way!), but I like your out-of-the-box approach and it should give me the insight I began looking for as to how close I am to bumping my head on the ceiling. Thanks!

Comment: This code seems to work, although running it on a new, blank database (no tables, queries, or forms... just a module with this function in it, running the function from the immediate window) says only 252 unused references/recordsets. I get the same number in my current app before opening any forms. Can this number be correct? I have seen 2048 given as the maximum available in recent versions of Access; apparently 1024 in older versions. Can Access be consuming almost 1800 of them before even opening a form?!

Comment: I did the same as you and got similar results.  And had the same thought.  It makes me wonder if the real number should actually be 256 as opposed to 2048/1096.  Do you remember where you saw that the limit was 2048?  I could not find it in any Microsoft documentation.

Comment: For example: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-specifications-HP005186808.aspx) and [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/906083-maximum-number-open-recordsets-access-2003-2007-a) and others from [this Google search](http://www.google.com/#q=access+recordsets+2048)

Comment: I'm led to the same conclusion as you, though I hate to leave things to supposition... hopefully someone will weigh in here sooner or later with some more definitive info. In the meantime, I'm going to suppose that whatever the 2048 limit is, as a practical matter I've got more like 256 to work with. Using your function, by the time my app is running - a main form with many controls and sub-forms - I've only got 40 unused slots remaining, and I've seen that go as low as mid-twenties if I open additional forms. I guess if the limit is ~250, then I've still got ~10% left?! Better than Err3048...

Comment: Thanks for the examples.  I just tried running this by replacing `CurrentDb` with a db object set using `OpenDatabase()` to an .mdb with no tables or database objects of any kind.  When I ran the function, it would run until `i` was equal to between 870 and 890 and then would fail with the error message: *3035: System resource exceeded.*  I am using Jet 4.0; perhaps that version of Jet has the 1024 limit?

Comment: Thanks for your further interest and info. When I do that on an empty .accdb file (db.version = 12.0; ACE, I think), it fails with the same error 3035 when the counter is around 435. I don't see any meaningful pattern here, do you?

Comment: The 435 is half of 870.  That may just be coincidence.  Or it may be that ACE 12.0 is using up system resources twice as fast as Jet 4.0.  Maybe a move from ANSI (8-bit) encoding to Unicode (16-bit) encoding?  Or 32-bit based storage to 64-bit?  These are just Scientific Wild Ass Guesses.  I really have no clue.