# Query results on Access form (VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am doing an Access project as a newbie and i am facing some problems (**have to do all in VBA**). In few words i have to show a query results on a form. I have few text boxes and i need to show some info. I understood that i have to change the RecordSource to the form and that i have to set the RecordSet for each text-box. Here is my code but is not working:

```vb
 Private Sub Form_open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strSQL As String, queryDef As DAO.queryDef
    strSQL = " *SELECT etc...* "
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "Info"
    Set queryDef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Info", strSQL)
    Me.RecordSource = queryDef.OpenRecordset() '**error here type mismatch
```

How can i change my RecordSource to a query that is created when open the form? 
(Tried already with `Me.RecordSet = strSQL` but is not working with INNER JOIN)
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Try `Me.Form.RecordSet = queryDef.OpenRecordset()`.

Answer (score 1):

You just mix up the forms recordsource and the forms recordset.

The recordsource`Me.RecordSource`is a string, that contains a table/query-name or a sql select statement.

```vb
Me.RecordSource = strSQL
```

A recordset is an object. Because of that, it has to be set

```vb
Set Me.RecordSet = queryDef.OpenRecordSet
```

Avoid the multiple usage of`CurrentDb`,store it in a variable.

Everytime it is used, a new copy of the database-instance (usually`DbEngine(0).Workspace(0)`) is created, what consumes unnecessary resources.

Some useful links on that topic:

- [The CurrentDb() Function](https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/the-currentdb-function.html)
- [CurrentDB.TableDefs vs db.TableDefs ... Object Invalid or Not Set Error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7ea9506f-5e91-4896-80b9-6712762388ea/currentdbtabledefs-vs-dbtabledefs-object-invalid-or-not-set-error?forum=accessdev)
- [MS Access: Is there a significant overhead when using CurrentDB as opposed to DBEngine(0)(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833746/ms-access-is-there-a-significant-overhead-when-using-currentdb-as-opposed-to-db)

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim db as DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String, queryDef As DAO.queryDef
    strSQL = " *SELECT etc...* "
    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set queryDef = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL) ' vbNullstring is "" but typo-safe. If you create a querydef with an empty name, it is just temporary and will get lost after querydef is terminated
    Set Me.RecordSet = queryDef.OpenRecordset()
```

Or just using the recordsource:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = " *SELECT etc...* "
    Me.RecordSource = strSQL
```

Comment: thank you very much! But why complex queries aren't working with the second choise ( = strSQL). Like it works with queries from one table but not with joins. It saying something as _can' t find ...\table\ .mdb_

Comment: Error in sql statement for sure. `Debug.Print strSQL` before assigining to recordsource and copy and paste the string into a new query (sql-view). This will show you the error when you try datasheet-view.

Comment: *Avoid the multiple usage ofCurrentDb,store it in a variable. Everytime it is used, a new copy of the database-instance is created, what consumes unnecessary resources.* :O never heard of that, but it's very interesting. Any source or documentation I can learn more about it?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Read [The CurrentDb() Function](https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/the-currentdb-function.html). Never failed on a tabledef (missing parent)?.Use it in loop and compare execution time to stored reference. I always use the `CurrentDbC`property, as shown in link.

Comment: Is there any difference in setting the forms recordsource vs its recordset? Thanks