# Optimal way to use Database.Execute method from VBA against MSSQL linked through ODBC

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, transactions, odbc

The Database.Execute DAO method has so many parameters and I'm not sure what would be the optimal way (fast, efficient and avoiding locks) to execute update and insert statements againts an MSSQL database from VBA code (MS Access). I'm accessing the MSSQL tables through ODBC.

[Database.Execute method (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao)

Now I'm using it as follows:

`CurrentDb.Execute "SQL statement comes here"`

or

`CurrentDb.Execute "SQL statement comes here", dbSeeChanges`

I have two scenarios:

- I want to update or insert data into business tables (customers, invoices etc.) - here I use the version with dbSeeChanges - because multiple users may read and write these tables at the same time
- I insert records into a log table - I use the plain version here - only inserts happen in this case, there's no read from these tables

But I'm not sure if this is really the best way to use it.

Comment: I mean honestly youre having access use its engine to effect the RDBMS on the back end. You should have your queries in pass thru's and fire them that way. Or Use a QDF.execute approach. Mainly because the heavy lifting ought to be on the tool that's best suited for the job, right? IDK maybe thats just a preference of mine but I often chose to style my methods on how I can use SQL Server's engine instead of Access's.

Comment: The application has hundreds of statements and rewriting them in order to use pass-through queries is not an option. (As far as I understood pass-through queries have to be written in a way that MS SQL can "understand", while current statements are written in a way Jet (Access) understands.)

Comment: So you don't want to use the best way? Why not rewrite queries when its usefull (you can mix Passthrough/MDAC)? Be aware of what [CurrentDb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1837922/9439330) does.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for the "optimal way", not the best way. Sometimes the technically best approach is simple not feasible. This is basically a 15 year old software, very close to the end of its lifecycle. So it does not worth investing hundreds of hours in rewriting hundreds of very complex statements. If I can easily optimize them (by adding the right parameters) than I will do it otherwise just leave it as it is.

Comment: If EOL, then don't bother with optimizing, but will the SQL Server DB get EOL too? If not (just createing a new frontend) then you will need to rewrite all access queries, that use MDAC/VBA specific methods. You may try the [SSMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/ssma/sql-server-migration-assistant?view=sql-server-ver15) and see what queries may need rewriting and what can be converted automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you use now is fine...have used myself in very large apps with SQL Server in the back end....

Comment: This should be a comment and is missing dbFailOnError!